# Core breakdown when I try to run Kivy-designer

Tags: android, kivy

I'm using a kivy over pycharm. I want to install a kivy designer to take advantage of Kivy's visual interface features. I installed the kivydesigner as written in the document with python3 but when I run it, I get an error like below; the popup comes on the screen and closes immediately.

```
stranger@paradise-citys-grasses:~/kivy-designer$ python3 -m designer
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/stranger/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-09-29_72.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.3 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:58:41)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.0 Mesa 17.0.7'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'X.Org'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Gallium 0.4 on AMD CEDAR (DRM 2.49.0 / 4.10.0-35-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.30'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[WARNING] [FileNotFoundError] [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/stranger/.kivy/garden/garden.xpopup/xpopup.mo'. Switch to the defaults.
[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: gtk3(['clipboard_dbusklipper'] ignored)
xclip version 0.12
Copyright (C) 2001-2008 Kim Saunders et al.
Distributed under the terms of the GNU GPL
[INFO   ] [Cutbuffer   ] Provider: xclip
[INFO   ] [CutBuffer   ] cut buffer support enabled
Parçalama arızası (çekirdek döküldü)
```

The last line in Turkish means "Crushing failure (core breakdown)".

Comment: I answered this on your [mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/Ue_3vjvcoZI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Note

The Kivy Designer is still a WIP (Work In Progress).

### Python 3.x, Kivy, Ubuntu 16.04/18.04 LTS (64-bits) - Crash

Problem running Kivy Designer on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it always crash.

### Python 3.x, Kivy, Windows 10 (64-bits) - Working

No problem running in on Windows 10 64-bits using Python 3.x.

### Solution for FileNotFoundError

There is a file by the name, `xpopup_ru.mo` in the folder, `.kivy/garden/garden.xpopup`. Rename `xpopup_ru.mo` to `xpopup.mo`, and it will solve the FileNotFoundError but Kivy Designer will still crash in the environment: Python 3.x, Kivy, Ubuntu 16.04/18.04 LTS (64-bits).

### Python2.x, Kivy, Ubuntu 16.04/18.04 LTS (64-bits) - Working

No problem running Kivy Designer

## Output

[image: Kivy Designer - New Project]
[image: Kivy Designer - log]

Answer (score 0):

I just moved the '__main__.py' to its parent folder and made below modifications after renaming the mo file to xpopup.mo:

```
import os
os.environ['GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH'] = 'quiet'
data = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'designer\data')
```

you can simply run this .py file from your IDE to launch the Kivy Designer.